# Has a small table within a big DB the same performance as the same small table within a small DB?

Tags: rdbms

Has a small table within a big DB the same performance as the same small table within a small DB?
(all about RDBMS)
I wanna understand do I need to split my DB or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, and without more precision on the actual RDBMS and its underlying OS, the question is close to asking whether performances for accessing a small file on a disk depend on the disk size. And the answer is that the size of the disk has no direct impact on the performances.

It could have *indirect* impacts, if splitting the DB ends in splitting it on a number of systems because it could increase scalability by also splitting the number of connections across the various DB. But those are only indirect impact, because caching parts of a large DB could achieve the same scalability without actualy splitting the DB.